# Sequelize MySQL Models

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

I am working with Express.js and MySQL database. I need to create models of tables thats why I've decided to use Sequelize, but I already have entire schema defined.

Is there any easy/fast way to generate models and relations from database to files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto). Here is a sample command to create your models.

`sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models] -t [tableName] -C`

NOTE: Note the parameter `-o [/path/to/models]` is the directory where you want to place your `models`.js files. If you don't specify the `-t` option, it will create models for all tables.